# How do I escape special characters in user input - I'm using sql server database

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-injection

Could someone help me..

I'm trying to escape special chars: " , ' backslash * and other special chars to prevent sql injection.

The problem here is that i'm using php and sql server.

I've searched a lot, but nothing that could really help me, specially with the ' char.

Here is my code:

```
public function query($sql)
{
    $result = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $sql);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Show the code you are using to insert the data into the database. Without that, nobody can help

Comment: @Pekka - I'm not having problems while saving data (without '). The problem arise when data contains '

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146546/mysql-real-escape-string-alternative-for-sql-server

Comment: @SamArulRaj thnx :) Problem solved

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother.

Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: What do you know, "use PDO" indeed is the correct and full answer for this case. Downvote removed :)

Comment: I was searching for something simple and faster.. thnx

Comment: @Mllena Arkh's suggestion really is the best way to go. Using home-brewn escaping functions isn't a nice idea really.

Comment: How is using something already existing not simpler than writing your own solution?

Beside that, it would simplify your code too - for instance error handling via exceptions would be waaay easier.

Answer (score -4):

mysql_real_escape_string  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
use it

Comment: I've used that with mysql, but i'm using sql server