# Database fetch row containing an Ampersand character truncates the return string

Tags: php, sql-server

Problem: sql = `select address from mytable were name like 'T%'`
returns address ok except where the address is like 'Cr James & Dennis Street'.  This value is returned truncated to 'Cr James'

My database is a mssql server.
I use the PHP ODBC driver with the following connection string:

```
$db = odbc_pconnect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};
Server=" . $SERVER . ";Database=". $Database. ";", $UID, $PWD);
```

Comment: can you show us the code where you are outputting the address in PHP? thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In mysql we can use mysqli_real_escape_string like:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like "%'.mysqli_real_escape_string("data & the base").'%"');
```

Read this post, perhaps it helps you:

> [mysql_real_escape_string alternative for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146546/mysql-real-escape-string-alternative-for-sql-server)

Comment: OP is talking about the return value: "(...) returns address ok except (...)"

Comment: Yes, the problem is '&' character, so, exclude and search Cr James Dennis Street instead Cr James & Dennis Street

Comment: and why should this change the returned value?