# How do you escape quotes in a sql query using php?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query

```
$sql ="SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer 
WHERE EmailAddress = '".addslashes($_POST['username']) ."' AND Password = '".addslashes($_POST['password']) ."'";

//  while printing,   it will be

SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE EmailAddress = 'test@ab\'c.com' AND Password = '123'
```

if we executing this in a mysql server it works, but not in a sql server

what is the solution for this? 
. Iam using sql server

Comment: Could you be clear whether you want to know how this is done in MySQL, or SQL Server? It looks like you really want the latter though your tags say otherwise.

Comment: i wants to work it  in SQL Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape strings in SQL Server using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php)

Comment: Addslashes was never safe ans has therefore been removed from PHP.  You need to find a tutorial or some other source of PHP information that's less than 15 years old.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`addslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) will escape single quotes with a leading backslash which is valid syntax in MySQL but not in MS SQL Server. The correct way to escape a single quote in MS SQL Server is with another single quote. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for MySQL ([`mysql_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) has been deprecated). Unfortunately, no analogous `mssql_` function exists so you'll have to roll your own using [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or something similar. Better yet, use a database neutral abstraction layer such as PDO that supports parameterized queries.

Comment: I'd +1 you, except that you linked to the same halfassed "quoting" function i just downvoted twice.

Comment: @cHao: I didn't look carefully enough at that function before I linked to it. I didn't notice it was mangling data. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I've removed the link to the offensive function from my answer.

Comment: PHP 7 UPDATE: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.  Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_real_escape_string(), 
PDO::quote()

Answer (score 7):

For MySQL, you want to use `mysql_real_escape_string`.  `addslashes` does almost the same thing and has fewer letters, but apparently it gets some stuff wrong -- don't use it.

For SQL Server, it's a bit more complicated, as (1) MySQL quotes stuff non-standardly, and (2) i don't see a function made to quote stuff for SQL Server.  However, the following should work for you...

```
$escaped_str = str_replace("'", "''", $unsafe_str);
```

Comment: `addslashes()` was designed for a different purpose and gets one subtle case wrong. Don't use it for escaping for MySQL.

Comment: @staticsan: I kinda figured there was a reason there was a whole other function (with a deprecated previous version!) to quote MySQL strings.  +1 for mentioning it.  :)  Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

for **mysql**

USE `mysql_real_escape_string`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

like :

```
// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

for **mssql**

look on the answers here :

[How to escape strings in SQL Server using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-mssql-using-php)

Comment: This works only for MySQL, not MS SQL Server. The poster appears to want a solution that works in MS SQL Server too.

Comment: if we do like that, the query will output  like
SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE EmailAddress='' AND Password=''

//  form values  are not outputing from mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: I wish i could downvote this answer again.  Your ms_escape_string function is the kind of stuff i pride myself on **not** doing -- the data should be validated by the caller, and if valid, should make it to the DB **unmodified**.

Comment: its example i link to the original question.

Comment: @haim evgi: And i downvoted the source of your example too.  No quoting function should mangle data -- its whole purpose in life is to see that data makes it into the DB unaffected by the database's quote syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't really be building the SQL statement dynamically as it's dangerous (and unnecessary).  The correct thing to do is to use a paramerised query see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296201%28SQL.90%29.aspx

```
$sql ="SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE EmailAddress = ? AND Password = ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']));
```

This is much safer and means you don't have to worry about escaping characters.  Another thing is beware of case sensitive / insensitve comparisons.  For example if you wanted email address to be case insensitive but password case sensitive use something like:

```
$sql ="SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE EmailAddress = ? COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CIAI AND Password = ? COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CSAS";
```