# PHP & SQL: Best way to protect this query from SQL injections NOT using PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have a query which is run against a mssql database and I'm not using PDO drivers. Is there something like prepared statement i can use?

Here is the query:

```
$tsql = "INSERT INTO cplinktable (liferayid, bmsid, autotaskid, waspdb, cpid) VALUES ($liferayid, $bmsid, $autotaskid, '$waspdb', $cpid)";
```

thanks,

Jonesy

Comment: You may find [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-mssql-using-php) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft SQL Driver for PHP provides prepared statements:

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=80e44913-24b4-4113-8807-caae6cf2ca05&displaylang=en
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc296184%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should at least escape the values.

[PHP Manual - mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO cplinktable (liferayid, bmsid, autotaskid, waspdb, cpid) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($liferavid),
            mysql_real_escape_string($bmsid),
            mysql_real_escape_string($autotaskid),
            mysql_real_escape_string($waspdb),
            mysql_real_escape_string($cpid));
```

Answer (score 0):

its as simple as useing mysql_real_escape on strings and typecasting on digits / ints / doubles

```
(int)$number; //Safe
(double)$double; //Safe
mysql_real_escape_string($string); //Safe
```

This used on every piece of data you insert into your database will be safe

Answer (score -3):

Try Prepare Statements with [sprint()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_sprintf.asp)

```
$tsql = "INSERT INTO cplinktable (liferayid, bmsid, autotaskid, waspdb, cpid) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, '%s', %d)";

$tsql = sprintf($tsql, $liferayid, $bmsid, $autotaskid, $waspdb, $cpid);
echo $tsql; // you would execute this but printing to the screen to show the query
```