# How to escape symbols in SQL query?

Tags: php, sql-server, escaping

In PHP-script i need to update title, content fields.
If I put "@" into content I get error "Description: Incorrect syntax near '@'."
I fixed with symbols ' ".
Is there any solution for escaping or framework for DB layer?

I'm forced to use f**ng MS SQL :(

Code:

```
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
$db_conn = $conn->open('bla-bla-password...');
$query = sprintf( "UPDATE page SET title='%s', page_content='%s' WHERE id=%d;", addslashes($title), addslashes($content), intval($id));
$rs = $db_conn->execute($query);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-mssql-using-php
get this from fast googling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PDO [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to escape special characters … not sprintf or addslashes.

Comment: Or at least avoid `addslashes()` like the plague and use your DB's native quoting function

Comment: Thanks.
Actually I think to use Yii, I think It can solve all common problems instead coding from scratch.