# PHP and SQL Server, how to make it secure?

Tags: php, sql-server, lamp

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

I am using that to connect from a LAMP environment to SQL Server. I noticed I don't have the neet functions like prepared statement and real_escape_string.

How can I make my query as secure as possible? Any help is appreciated.

Don't suggest me to use ODBC or PDO, I don't have that option. I have to run with what I have, and that's MSSQL.

```
$con = mssql_connect ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

mssql_select_db('xxx', $con);

$qry = "SELECT 
            firstname
    FROM 
            person
    where firstname = '{$firstname}'";

$query = mssql_query($qry, $con);
```

Comment: @Kerrek: Answer some of his questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use literals, use parameters and [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php) them to your query:

```
$con = mssql_connect ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
mssql_select_db('xxx', $con);
$qry = 'SELECT firstname
     FROM person
    where firstname = @firstname';
mssql_bind ($qry, '@firstname', $firstname, SQLVARCHAR);
$query = mssql_query($qry, $con);
```

Comment: according to the docs, "mssql_bind — Adds a parameter to a stored procedure or a remote stored procedure" ...this won't work in my case since it's not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

[The MSSQL binding supports prepared statements just fine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php).

The documentation is your friend.

Comment: I did read the documentation, I couldn't find it.. mssql_bind is only for stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `htmlentities()` to convert html elements into html entities and this function accepts a third argument which is for escaping single and double quotes.

Here is the signature of the function:

```
string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT [, string $charset [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )
```

and the arguments that second parameters may take:

**ENT_COMPAT**  Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone.

**ENT_QUOTES**  Will convert both double and single quotes.

**ENT_NOQUOTES**    Will leave both double and single quotes unconverted.

**ENT_IGNORE**   Silently discard invalid code unit sequences instead of returning an empty string. Added in PHP 5.3.0. This is provided for backwards compatibility; avoid using it as it may have security implications.

**And**

You can simply use `addslashes()` with `htmlentities()`

and also there is another function with cleans html tags out from the fields which is `filter_var ()` and such example look would be:

$return_value = `filter_var($data_to_be_filtered,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

**Important**

Don't forget to check whether magic_quotes are enabled or not. You can do that by writing :

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    //do something
```

More about magic_quotes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

**Edit:**

You can do more secure transaction by using prepared-statements. They prevent SQL-Injection.

***Sample code:***

```
$db = new mysqli();
$db->real_connect($host,$username,$password,$db) or die("Cannot connect");
$query = "select name from users where id = ?";
$st = $db->prepare($query); //faster than normal query run
$st->bind_param("d",$id);
$st->execute();
$st->bind_result($name);
$st->fetch();
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mssql doesn't supply a function to escape your query.  One option is to use "addslashes()" instead, although it is somewhat ugly (and doesn't encompass everything)

This might be helpful: [How to escape strings in SQL Server using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-mssql-using-php)

Comment: how does that make it more secure?

Comment: It prevents it from SQL injections, which is your biggest fear with SQL queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, addslashes() is - at best - half of a solution (as this person has already been told in other help fora). It's pretty trivial to break addslashes().

Comment: Sorry, Chris, I was trying to emphasize the point for vick, not disparage your answer. :)

Comment: Actually there is a function with returns quoted string with slashed. Please check this function which is a native mySQL function :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote

Comment: how is escaping or removing slashes preventing sql injections?

Comment: @vick addslashes() attempts to escape SQL injection characters such as  single quotes.

Comment: @Braveyard - he's using Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL), not MySQL.

Comment: @TML : Oooo sorry I didn't see that... :) When PHP comes into play, it reminds me mySQL all the time :)