# Php to MsSql query - escape quotes (') issue

Tags: php, sql-server, escaping, quotes

I'm building my query:

```
$q = sprintf("UPDATE testTable SET Text='%s', [Read]=0, TimeUpdated='%s', [From]='%s' WHERE ID='%s'", ms_escape_string($text), $dateReceived, $from, $convID);
```

and I execute it:

```
$res = mssql_query($q, $dbhandle);
```

`$text` should be free text so it could contain all sorts of weird characters (for now let's stick to ASCII). The simplest scenario is when $text contains a quote, e.g. `$text = "Mc'Donalds"`

Inside the [ms_escape_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-mssql-using-php) function I try to prevent this by replacing ' with 2 quotes ''.
I echo the query string:

```
UPDATE testTable SET Text='Mc''Donalds', [Read]=0, TimeUpdated='2012-08-03 12:44:49', [From]='bogus' WHERE ID='14'
```

(Note: executing this query from the VS server explorer on the same db works just fine)

Everything seems ok - see the double quotes for Mc''Donalds - but it still fails when executing:  `[mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near 'Mc'`

I thought that SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER might be the culprit so I tried

```
 $q = "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF";
 $resq = mssql_query($q,$dbhandle);
```

before executing my query but no cigar - I still get the same error.

Now I'm stuck - what should I change to get strings containing single quotes to pass through?

Comment: **whoa.** i wouldn't use `sprintf` to generate a sql statement like that.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you expand on that? As long as the arguments are properly escaped, I don't see an inherent problem with it, although I've never done it myself...

Comment: its risky. and it also causes the OP's problem

Comment: @DanielA.White Fair enough, but can you explain *why*?

Comment: @Ando I would (in general, not just in the face of the current problem) suggest you look at [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) because `mssql_*` functions can be a total PITA and sqlsrv has easy support for prepared statements and has a PDO driver

Comment: ok -it's not the best way of writing the query - other alternatives? (without using PDO)

Comment: @Ando - why no pdo? it would solve many problems.

Comment: now I'm switching to PDO (or sqlsrv) because I can't get around this quotes issue. Though the question is still valid- it should be possible with mssql_* - what's the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: 1. Do not use `mysql_` use summat like `mysqli` instead. 2. use `prepare` and `bind` set of functions. Lot less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems more to do with the lack of a native mssql_real_escape_string() function, which is addressed [by this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-mssql-using-php?rq=1).

You should be more worried about an SQL injection attack, a problem many of us have finally put to bed by preferring to use PDO, as has been mentioned in the comments.

This type of "Escaping in readiness for the next recipient of the data" forms part of the FIEO mantra (Filter Input Escape Output).

Comment: I've read the thread before asking my question - the  ms_escape_string is taken from there. Now I'm switching to PDO - but the question is still valid.

Comment: The comments under that code you pulled out suggest that solution may not be 100% solid and your OP seems to confirm it - sorry not to be able to add much more to the discussion then.