# codeigniter escape value error

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping

I'm using codeigiter 2.1.3, I have simple query bind, but when i run this i get below error. I even used same thing with active records, but still i get the same error. Querying data from MsSql using ODBC connection.

```
$searchTerm = $this->db->escape_like_str("st'm");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM arcus WHERE id LIKE ? OR name = ?";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($searchTerm, $searchTerm));

Error Number: 37000

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'm'.

SELECT * FROM arcus WHERE id LIKE '%st\'m%' {escape '!'}
OR name LIKE '%st\'m%' {escape '!'}

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\XX\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: I think that you can report that at CI issues at github - https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues 

Do you have other params for that search ?

Comment: using query binding automatically escapes it so no need to use
 `$this->db->escape_like_str("st'm");`

Comment: Even though i removed $this->db->escape_like_str(), query binding is not escaping the data, its gives data as it is = st'm

Comment: how about using regular escape? `$this->db->escape()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, codeigniter for not escaping the value as MsSql wanted. Like for MsSql single quotes are escape like ('st''m') where for mysql ('st\'m'). Codeigniter was doing it in a wrong way. This post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php) helped me with below function to escape quotes for MsSql. Its working now. Thanks for your suggestions.

```
 function ms_escape_string($data) {
    if ( !isset($data) or empty($data) ) return '';
    if ( is_numeric($data) ) return $data;

    $non_displayables = array(
        '/%0[0-8bcef]/',            // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
        '/%1[0-9a-f]/',             // url encoded 16-31
        '/[\x00-\x08]/',            // 00-08
        '/\x0b/',                   // 11
        '/\x0c/',                   // 12
        '/[\x0e-\x1f]/'             // 14-31
    );
    foreach ( $non_displayables as $regex )
        $data = preg_replace( $regex, '', $data );
    $data = str_replace("'", "''", $data );
    return $data;
}
```