# Any command or method to replace mysql_real_escape_string? -Using sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlsrv

I have been trying to find a way in which it has the same outcome as using mysql_real_escape_string. I do know that sqlsrv does not have the command for escaping string, but I need the escape string function. Is there any command or method that does escape string for sqlsrv? I tried addslashes, but what it did was to input the slashes into the database as well, which unfortunately is not what I wanted. I just wanted this escape string to help as some of the inputs into database has special characters like ' in which there is problem inserting to database. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php

Comment: Yes, there is - it is called [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740) (addslashes is *never* correct for SQL)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Thank you so much for the link! Apparently I think I did str_replace before, but did not do correctly, hence the database show double quotes. Following the solution given in it, I managed to insert it correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, I found the solution already, but still, Thank you!

Comment: @Jolene Using a manual str_replace is also incorrect.

Comment: @user2864740 >< I see, because actually what I really wanted to ensure is that the ' quote can be inserted into database. Using str_replace did achieve that, but as to how to escape string... it's still a question to me.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you'll want to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database access.  It wraps the logic from various databases into a single API.

Not all files are included with PHP for using PDO.  Specifically, you'll need the SqlSrv driver from Microsoft's site... however, [version 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) only supports PHP 5.3 and 5.4.  Older versions will need [version 2.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV20.EXE).

PHP 5.5 needs an [unofficial release](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86?forum=sqldriverforphp) modified from the source code on CodePlex.

**Note: There does not seem to be driver files for other OSes.**

You will need two files to php.ini for PDO support, but which two depends on if PHP is compiled as thread-safe and which PHP version it is.

PDO contains both methods to do [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (recommended) and [quote values](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

Comment: Woah, I'm sorry but it's a little complicated for me. However, I tried str_replace and it worked perfectly. Thank you still!