# Escape string in mssql/php

Tags: php, sql-server, string, escaping, sqlsrv

I want to insert html-code in database. How can I correctly escape string?

```
$html = '<tag>';
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET text = ? WHERE id = 1';
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$html));
sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
```

This code throw error: Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: `array(&$html));` that ampersand `&` shouldn't be in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2526717/4621324

Comment: Your code is absolutely good. What versions of PHP and SQLSRV do you use? It might be a bug in PHP extension.

Answer (score -2):

Escape the HTML with

```
htmlspecialchars($html)
```

This function changes `<` to the HTML code for `&lt;`

This will fix you problem.