# PHP with SQL Server (No MySQL please) - Select Statement with LIKE in the WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I hate PHP, but I have to do this. I have spent the last 2 days searching for a simple way to write a SQL Select with a LIKE clause where the parameter is passed from the `lname` input text on the form. Now, it has to be `SQL Server`, NOT `MYSQL`

So here is what I've done so far.

```
    function getActorDetailsLnameOnly($lname) {
    // the SQL query to be executed on the database

    $query = "select NameFirst, NameLast, Age, Gender from actor where NameLast like '%$lname%'";

    return executeQuery($query);
}
```

on the **index.php**, I wrote the following:

```
if ((!empty($_REQUEST['lname'])) and ( empty($_REQUEST['age']) and ( empty($_REQUEST['gender'])))) {

        $lname = (string) $_GET['lname'];

        $sql = getActorDetailsLnameOnly($lname);
        foreach ($sql as ...) {
            extract(...);
           ...
```

The code returns a value, but it's nowhere near correct. It's like requesting A in the select statement and it's returning Z. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Post your test cases.

Comment: Did you write `executeQuery`? Mysql and sqlserver in this instance will have the same syntax; depending on the driver you are using. We also need to know what you are querying and what is being returned.

Comment: I'm querying a SQL Server using PDO and I'm trying to return every value in the table where the last name like %whatever% I enter into the Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?PHP if (isset($_POST['lname'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']); ?>">

Comment: Also, yes, I am calling the executeQuery in the dbconn php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check form input values through `$_REQUEST['lname']` and then assign a variable `$lname = (string) $_GET['lname'];`. If form method is **POST** then `$_REQUEST['lname']` would have the value and `$_GET['lname']` would be empty. As the result `like` pattern would be `'%%'`, which is effectively everything but `NULL`.

Basically, `$_GET` is for **GET**, `$_POST` is for **POST** and `$_REQUEST` is for any.

Try using `$lname = (string) $_REQUEST['lname'];`.

Comment: Using your reply gave me a good idea. When I applied your suggestion, I also changed my SQL query. Now, it works like a charm!  The New Query is:: $query = "SELECT NameFirst, NameLast, Age, Gender FROM Actor WHERE NameLast like '%{$_POST['lname']}%'";

Comment: @dot3tech Glad that helped. Please do sanitize input though [How to escape strings in SQL Server using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php)