# SQL Server Escape String

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php) question as a reference. My issue is that it's encoding my string to hex, but not decoding it once it's written to the database.

HTML textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="nomInfo[]" id="appNom" placeholder="Additional Information"></textarea>
```

Getting POST value and inserting into the DB

```
function mssql_escape($data) {
    if(is_numeric($data))
        return $data;
    $unpacked = unpack('H*hex', $data);
    return '0x' . $unpacked['hex'];
}   

$nomInfo = $_POST['nomInfo'][0];

$nomInfoDecode = mssql_escape($nomInfo);

$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.emp_recog (nomInfo) VALUES (";
$query .= "'" . $nomInfoDecode . "');";
```

So for example, if I types in `ggfdgdfg/fdg.fdgdf.gdf "fdskfdskfds;fsd ' sdfds' fds/f%` into the textarea and submit the form, this is written to the database `0x67676664676466672f6664672e66646764662e676466205c226664736b6664736b6664733b667364205c272073646664735c27206664732f6625`

Comment: This seems like overkill when a prepared statement would avoid the need for escape strings. EDIT: but to answer your question, remove the apostrophes on the second line of your $query thing.

Comment: e.g. `$query .= "'" . $nomInfoDecode . "');";` -> `$query .= $nomInfoDecode . ");";` since the apostrophes make you literally put in '0x67676664676466672f6664672e66646764662e676466205c226664736b6664736b6664733b667364205c272073646664735c27206664732f6625' as opposed to what that hex value represents.

Comment: That makes sense and looks correct but for some reason it still wrote the hex string to the database after doing exactly what you said. @ZLK

Comment: How does your query actually execute?

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 1):

Scrap all the hex stuff, there is no need.  Really the only thing to worry about escaping is a quote `'`.  MySQL uses a slash `\` as an escape character.  MS SQL uses a quote `'` to escape a quote `'`, so you just double-up the quotes:

```
return str_replace("'", "''", $data );
```

However, you really should be using [PHP Data Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) that supports MS SQL, then there is [PDO::quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

Comment: hope this works every other solution fails me

Comment: @TechnoloJesus Should be using PDO now days, then just use https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the example is not quoting the value to be inserted:

```
mssql_query('
  INSERT INTO sometable (somecolumn)
  VALUES (' . mssql_escape($somevalue) . ')
');
```

which translated to your query using double quotes would be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.emp_recog (nomInfo) VALUES (";
$query .= $nomInfoDecode . ");";
```

Can you give that a shot?

Comment: btw, i might opt to take advantage of the double quotes like this: $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.emp_recog (nomInfo) VALUES ($nomInfoDecode)";

Comment: That makes sense and looks correct but for some reason it still wrote the hex string to the database after doing exactly what you said. @WEBjuju