# php mssql escape special characters

Tags: php, sql-server

Trying to run the following query string (against MS SQL Server) which includes special characters. How do I do this?

```
select top 1 Contact_CustomData.CustomFields.value('(/CustomFields[1]/GiftCard)[1]', 'varchar(100)') from Contact_CustomData;
```

This query (when executed directly on the db) works fine.  Just need to escape these characters somehow.

Comment: `these` ?? In your current  query no char needs to be escaped.

Comment: You have only to escape `'` like so `\'` or so `''` if these chars part of data/content.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I'm sorry I don't understand your comment. Would you please explain differently?

Comment: Normaly a query looks like `SELECT * FROM abc WHERE a='b'`, in case you have an single quote in it you have to do it like  `SELECT * FROM abc WHERE a='b\'s'`.

Comment: But check this http://www.aaronlrutledge.com/escaping-special-characters-in-php-for-mssql/     im not know so much about mssql, but single quote escaping i done mostly in the same way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape strings in SQL Server using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php)