# Escape String in SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Whenever I implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574821/3261339) code, I no longer get an error while using a single quote, but the hexstring get's written to the database instead of being converted back to the original characters.

```
function mssql_escape($data) {
    if(is_numeric($data))
        return $data;
    $unpacked = unpack('H*hex', $data);
    return '0x' . $unpacked['hex'];
}

mssql_query('
    INSERT INTO sometable (somecolumn)
    VALUES (' . mssql_escape($somevalue) . ')
');
```

This is what I'm trying to do. $suggestTest is the variable I'm using the escape function on.

```
$nomDept = $_POST['nomDept'];
$subSupervisor = $_POST['subSupervisor'];
$suggestion = $_POST['suggestion'];

$suggestTest = mssql_escape($suggestion);

if ($subSupervisor == "Yes") {
    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.emp_recog (nomDept, nomSuggestion, subSupervisor) VALUES (";
    $query .= "'" . $nomDept . "', ";
    $query .= "'" . $suggestTest . "', ";
    $query .= "'" . $subSupervisor . "');";
    $res = mssql_query($query);
}
```

I've also tried omitting the single quotes around the variable like so

```
if ($subSupervisor == "Yes") {
    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.emp_recog (nomDept, nomSuggestion, subSupervisor) VALUES (";
    $query .= "'" . $nomDept . "', ";
    $query .= $suggestTest ", ";
    $query .= "'" . $subSupervisor . "');";
    $res = mssql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: can you explain "hexstring get's written to the database instead of being converted back to the original characters"

Comment: you are using return '0x'.XYZXYX; which is Hexa

Comment: Did you check hexdec()

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND I must have misunderstood the answer to that question. So the intention is for hex to be written to the database using this function? I was under the impression that the function converted the characters to hex to carry out the sql statement, then was converted back to the original characters to write to the DB.

Comment: Users voted negative for unpack('H*hex', $data); just go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php#108599

Comment: hexdec  will convert HEX to DEC and then you can pass it to the query

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Answer (score -1):

If you use prepare to build your SQL statement, you do not need to escape the variables.