# How can I escape strings using sqlsrv_* functions?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

How can i use `real_escape_string` in sqlsrv?

This is my code:

```
$uname = sqlsrv_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['uname']));
$pass  = sqlsrv_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['pword']));
```

but I recieve the following error:

> undefined function `sqlsrv_real_escape_string`

Comment: This might be a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php

Comment: If you use prepared statements with binds, this should solve a lot of the problems that real escape string is designed to cover.

Comment: In general *_escape_string is to wrong way to do escaping. You should use prepared statements with bind parameters and let the database handle all the escaping. Try looking into PDO

Comment: As far as I know they never cared writing such feature (probably because it's a modern extension and the functionality wouldn't specially useful). If it's important for you, you may want to try whether the PDO flavour implements [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

Comment: If any of the answers provided is helpful, please upvote them, and mark accepted the one question that best answered your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The SQL Server code makes prepared statements very easy to do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?";
$parameters = [$_POST["uname"], $_POST["pword"]];
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parameters);
```

Simply replace your values with a `?` and then pass them as an array (in order) as the third argument to `sqlsrv_query()`.

(Not that you would ever store plaintext passwords in a databse, right?)

Answer (score -2):

I understand why you would want to use this to capture innocent ' and weed out SQL injections, but there is no such function sqlsrv_real_escape_string. You could make your own function or use preg_replace and add `'\'`. Just a thought.

[Take a look at the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574805/1575353)